# how to simulate NUMA in gem5?

Tags: gem5, numa

gem5 how to build NUMA architecture?  I know gem5 supports analog NUMA architecture. but I did not find the relevant information under the official library, I didn't find the configuration information or tutorial in the gem5 config directory.

where should I find the relevant tutorial or information?